# Git me indica un usuario anterior y no lo puedo cambiar. que hago?

Tags: git, github

Estoy tratando de subir mi proyecto a un repositorio a mi nombre, meses anteriores le preste mi PC a un amigo para que suba sus proyectos en Git.

Configuré los usuarios globales y locales y me sigue diciendo que otro usuario intenta subir al repositorio actual, tengo este maldito error:

> $ git push -u origin main
> remote: Permission to FrancoGT/sistAlli.git denied to GonzaloSegundo.
> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/FrancoGT/sistAlli.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Agradezco de antemano que me digan una solución

Comment: Al hacer un push no se usa el user.name o user.email (global o local). Ahi lo que importa es la configuración que tienes en el remoto.

Answer (score 1):

Yo tuve ese mismo error, tuve que borrar las credenciales de git de Windows, y el problema se soluciono, basicamente era porque git pensaba que era otra persona.[image: El programa es Administrar Credenciales De Windows]

Y elimina todo lo que contenga la palabra GIT
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y le picas en remove o eliminar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que te haya servido

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente era eliminar una credencial que se había almacenado en mi Windows por defecto, por eso estaba en esa jaula del usuario incorrecto